# Advice on ElasticSearch Cluster Configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Brand new to Elasticsearch.  I've been doing tons of reading, but I am hoping that the experts on SO might be able to weigh in on my cluster configuration to see if there is something that I am missing.

Currently I am using ES (1.7.3) to index some very large text files (~700 million lines) per file and looking for one index per file.  I am using logstash (V2.1) as my method of choice for indexing the files.  Config file is here for my first index:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "L:/news/data/*.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"       
        sincedb_path => "C:/logstash-2.1.0/since_db_news.txt"
    }
}

filter {
    csv {
        separator => "|"
        columns => ["NewsText", "Place", "Subject", "Time"]
    }
mutate {
    strip => ["NewsText"]
    lowercase => ["NewsText"]
}
}


output {
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["xxx.xxx.x.xxx", "xxx.xxx.x.xxx"]
        index => "news"
        workers => 2
        flush_size => 5000
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

My cluster contains 3 boxes running on Windows 10 with each running a single node.  ES is not installed as a service and I am only standing up one master node:

> Master node: 8GB RAM,  ES_HEAP_SIZE = 3500m,  Single Core i7
>
> Data Node #1: 8GB RAM,  ES_HEAP_SIZE = 3500m, Single Core i7
>
> This node is currently running the logstash instance with LS_HEAP_SIZE= 3000m
>
> Data Node #2: 16GB RAM, ES_HEAP_SIZE = 8000m, Single Core i7

I have ES currently configured at the default 5 shards + 1 duplicate per index.

At present, each node is configured to write data to an external HD and logs to another.

In my test run, I am averaging 10K events per second with Logstash.  My main goal is to optimize the speed at which these files are loaded into ES.  I am thinking that I should be closer to 80K based on what I have read.

I have played around with changing the number of workers and flush size, but can't seem to get beyond this threshold.  I think I may be missing something fundamental.

My questions are two fold:

1) Is there anything that jumps out as fishy about my cluster configuration or some advice that may improve the process?

2) Would it help if I ran an instance of logstash on each data node indexing separate files?

Thanks so much for any and all help in advance and for taking the time to read.

-Zinga

Comment: this sounds like a better job for [sf]

Comment: Oh thanks @DanielA.White...I did not even know about that.  I will post there.

Answer (score 0):

i'd first have a look at whether logstash or es is the bottleneck in your setup. try ingesting the file without the es output. what throughtput are you getting from plain/naked logstash.

if this is considerably higher then you can continue on the es side of things. A good starter might be:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html

If plain logstash doesn't yield a significant increase in throughput you can can try increasing / parallelising logstash across your machines.

hope that helps